# Фиксация положения фона с помощью JS работает прерывисто

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend, sass

Я фиксирую положение фона блока в JS, чтобы создать эффект параллакса (`background-attachment: fixed` не подходит, так как работает этот атрибут очень багованно). Но иногда это работает так себе: фон может поменять положение не сразу.

Пример тут: https://youtu.be/SshLhAfD3oY

CSS:

```
.box {
    width: 100%;
    height: 1000px;
    background-image: url("e4AAAgCw3OA-960.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
    background-position-y: var(--check);
}
```

JS:

```
function parallax() {
    document.body.style = `--check: ${window.pageYOffset}px`;
}

window.addEventListener('scroll', (e) => {
    parallax();
});
```

Я менял `window.pageYOffset` на `window.scrollY`, но изменений никаких.

Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 0):

Для фиксированного фона на странице использую псевдоэлемент ::before и свойства CSS - position: fixed; z-index: -1;

```css
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: sans-serif;
    position: relative;
}

.header {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    padding: 20px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
    color: yellow;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px black;
}

.header::before {
    content: "";
    background-image: url('http://surl.li/lxwkl');
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: -1;
}

.main {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: center;
    color: white;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.772);
    min-height: 100vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="header">
  <h1>ПРОКРУТИ В НИЗ</h1>
</div>
<div class="main">
  <h1>ФОН ЗАФИКСИРОВАН</h1>
</div>
```